# Two ways of passing model back from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in MVC and have a question of principle about the way how the model is passed back from the view to the controller.

In the usual way the model-object comes from the controller, "spreads" its data into fields of the view and is then gone. The data will then be re-collected by a FormCollection-object passed back to the controller.

But there is also the other way where the model-object itself can be passed back to the controller as routedObject  of e.g. an ActionLink, URL-Action or whatever. Then it's not necessary to spread and re-collect all the data.

In my work-place the other way is blocked, I get a warning about forbidden chars in the link-string. When investigating the issue I found that the other way seems mostly unknown.
For many reasons I think it's much better to pass the model-object back instead of the elaborate re-collecting of data.

So what is the reason for this curiosity please?

Update: Added View-Example

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.TestClass
@{
    @(Model.TestValue = 111);
}

<a href="@Url.Action("ValueBack", Model)">
    <span>Test</span>
</a>



public void ValueBack(MvcApplication2.Models.TestClass testClass)
{
    int x = testClass.TestValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In MVC we can get the values of the form in the controller by 3 ways.

- Using the FormCollection Object.
- Using the Parameters.
- Strongly type model binding to view.

And I think it is not possible to send the model to the controller through the actionlink (as an ActionLink helper generates an anchor tag which when clicked sends a GET request to the server)

**The Another Way :**

**`Send the id of current model so that the controller action can fetch it back from the datastore from which it initially fetched it when rendering the View.`**

View:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Next", 
    "Step",
    new { 
        StepId = 2,
        id = Model.Id
    }, 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "stepContainer" }, 
    new { @class = "button" }
)
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Step(int StepId, int id)
{
    var model = Repository.GetModel(id);
    //Code
}
```

Comment: Quote Neon-X: "And I think it is not possible to send the model to the controller through the actionlink"

I have added a small example (made with "VS-Express for the Web").
The value in x is 111 after the routed model-object came back.